# Is this the correct way of handling large images efficiently (to avoid outOfMemoryErrorin Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory, android-bitmap

After lots of attempts thanks to all the Android enthusiasts, I've found a method to handle large images efficiently in Android Applications in order to get rid of outOfMemory error. But I really need to know is this the correct formal way of doing this. Or Do I need to add some more or any changes should be done. Please comment.

```
Bitmap bitmap1;

iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);

BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image2);
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image3);

int srcWidth = o.outWidth;
int srcHeight = o.outHeight;
int dstWidth = 600;        
 int dstHeight = 450;
int inSampleSize = 1;               
if (srcHeight > dstHeight || srcWidth > dstWidth) {
            final int halfHeight = srcHeight / 2;
            final int halfWidth = srcWidth / 2;
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > dstWidth
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > dstWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }        
        o.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1, o);
        iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);


        bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image2, o);
        iv2.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "DEcoded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image3, o);
        iv3.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        bitmap1.recycle();
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Bitmap Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: try here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ... but first thought is WTF those lines are doing `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1 to 2);` do you know that in `o.outWidth` is only width from last image (image3) ?

Comment: I did not get your point. Could you please further explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your code is doing the same thing as [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap).

The idea is that if we're trying to show a Bitmap in a 300*300 View area, we don't need to load the fairly large, say 1000*1000 Bitmap resource to memory. Just get the aspect ratio first and then decode it to a relatively smaller bitmap to save memory (and avoid OOM).

So I think this should be enough.